# I don't understand why this constructor does not work

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

I have a simple FiniteStateMachine, and the states for the FSM are classes that inherit from the `FSMState` abstract class, wich forces implementation of certain methods and fields, the `ownerClass` field is a generic type, so each state holds a reference to the class that owns the instance of the FSM

```
public abstract class FSMState<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the owner class of this State.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract T ownerClass { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID name of this State.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public FSMState(T owner, string name)
    {
        ownerClass = owner;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

So a state class would look something like this

```
public class MovingState : FSMState<AI>
{
    protected override AI ownerClass { get; set; }

    public override string Name { get; set; }

    //Contructor.
    public MovingState(AI owner, string name)
    {
        ownerClass = owner;
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

But the constructor does not works, I get these 2 errors

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter owner of FSMState.FSMState(AI, string)
>
> Error: The type FSMState does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

I don't know if doing this is possible, I want the classes that inherits form `FSMState` to implement a constructor that sets the fields `Name` and `ownerClass` but the `ownerClass` field must be generic

I'm trying to do something that is not possible?

Comment: Once you provide a constructor, you must also provide a no argument constructor if you ever plan on instantiating the object without arguments.

Comment: Plus, you can't _force_ the implementation of a particular constructor.  Constructors aren't inherited in C#, so there's no mechanism for an "abstract" constructor.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It sounds like he *doesn't* ever plan on having the object be instantiated without arguments.

Comment: @Servy His error message shows he's trying to do that somewhere.  Without seeing the implementation code; I'm only guessing based on the error message.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The explicit constructor is implicitly calling the parameter-less constructor.  That it doesn't find one is the cause of the other error message (for there being no two-parameter constructor).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the base class constructor in `MovingState`:

```
public MovingState(AI owner, string name)
    : base(owner, name)
{
}
```

Comment: (S)he still needs to invoke the base class constructor or provide a zero parameter constructor.

Comment: @YotamSalmon - You have to invoke the base class constructor, which takes two parameters. If you don't do it explictly, the parameterless one will be invoked but none exists on `FSMState<T>`, hence the error. They could add a parameterless constructor to the base class, but it's more likely they just need to call the existing constructor with the parameters given.

Comment: @Lee this worked out, it took the error away, i will need more time to see if it actually worked

Comment: @Lee, for now i will give you the answer, since this took out all errors, thanks!